# Probability with buttons on a cirlce that can turn black or white.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got an interesting problem today, on my University probability Competetion.
Here is the problem.

Let $n$ be an odd number. There are $n$ buttons on a circle that are coloured either black or white.Pressing a button change the colour of it's two adjacent buttons but not itself or any other buttons.Suppose the buttons are black or white with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and are independent of eachother.Given any initial conguration what is the probability that all buttons on the circle can turn to same color after some sequence of moves.

Here is my approach.

Solution: Let $0$ for black and $1$ for white.

Define ,

$S_{k}=(a_{1,k},a_{2,k},...,a_{n,k})$

Where $S_{k}$ are strings of $0,1$

$$A_{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i,k}$$

Where $S_{k}$ is the configuration at the $k^{th}$ round and $A_k$ be it's corresponding sum, $k ,A_{k}\geq 0$

Note that each time the sum change by $+2$ or $-2$ given any configuration, Thus $A_k\equiv A_{0} \pmod{2}$. Note that because of this reason we can perform suitable sequence of moves such that any possible sum is reached $\leq n$ that is if we have $A_0$ odd then $1,3,5,...,n$ all reached by finite sequence of operations, If $A_0$ is even then $0,2,....,n-1$ all values are reached by finite sequence of operations also pressing any button consecutively $2$ times we can reach the same state. Hence given any initial configuration we can reach to same color after finite sequence of moves after passing through all possible coloring with sum $\pmod{2}$  invariant(possibly repetations of step may occur) .Hence the probability is $1$.
$\blacksquare$

Actually my wordings in the exam are not like this one but I have done the same on exam except for the wordings.
Proof gotta same.

I just want to know is it correct ?

If yes any other good proof? If not please provide me with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Actually, I was expecting someone would tell me that either you need to give algorithim of explicit construction or You need to show that such such construction exist by mathematical proof logic.Although for completation of the proof see the last three comments in comment section of the proof , where I avoid algorthim but showed such construction exist by proof.

$\blacksquare$

Remark:

Also note that for $n=even$ we cannot reach the step with all $0,0,...,0$ or $1,1,....,1$ if we start with odd number of one's because of parity reasons.

Comment: I think your conclusion may be correct, but I am not convinced by your argument.  If there two adjacent $1$s and the rest $0$s (so a sum of $2$)  with $n\ge 5$, I see then after the next step you will have a sum of $2$ or $4$ but not $0$ since you cannot change two adjacent values in a single step, so I do not see why this will guarantee that you can get to $0$ with more steps

Comment: I am not saying that pressing 1 again and again decrease from 2 to 0 or 4 to 2 to 0

Comment: When we have two adjacent 1's do this , (1,1,0,0,0) press the 2nd 0 from left (1,1,1,0,1) which can be rephrased as (0,1,1,1,1) now press 3rd one , (0,0,1,0,1) which can be rephrased as (1,0,1,0,0) now press the 2nd 0, (0,0,0,0,0)

Comment: In exam hall in rough work I check all odd number and all configuration possibly excluding related cases and I checked Upto 3,5,7,9,11 and all worked.

Comment: Then I realised this is happening

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read attentively your question. This is not a reason for downvoting at once my answer.

Comment: Who down vote,  I don't even know lol!!!

Comment: There are situations where pressing a button does not change the sum: $(\ldots, 0, x, 1, \ldots) \mapsto (\ldots 1, x, 0, \ldots)$.  So it's convincing that each move preserves the parity of the sum, but reaching any value is another matter.

Comment: No it's not I can explain.Wait a bit I am working on a problem,  after that I will comment.

Comment: Consider the sequence $A_0=n$  clearly we can perform sequence of moves such that $A_0\geq A_1\geq ...\geq A_k\geq....$ hence the sequence is eventually constant as $A_{k}\geq 1$(over some possible sequence of move) but note that performing If we reach $A_{k}=1$ then the sequence must visit all possible number between as a number never gets up when it's downing, Suppose that not the case that not the case $A_{k}=g\geq 3$ then Over all possible moves we are getting $g$ continuously and that doesn't happen because of the $-2$ downlift reason.

Comment: Now note that , We can reach any step to any step as pressing 2 times the same button we can actually did nothing, hence we can backtrack.

Answer (score 3):

> Note that each time the sum change by $+2$ or $−2$ given any configuration.

This is not completely accurate. Sometimes, the sum changes by $+0$.

> Note that because of this reason we can perform suitable sequence of moves such that any possible sum is reached $≤n$ that is if we have $A_0$ odd then $1,3,5,...,n$ all reached by finite sequence of operations,

This is true, but you have not offered proof. You need to describe a specific strategy which shows you can attain these values. While you have shown that the parity of the number of colors cannot change, it is plausible you would get stuck somewhere as you try to increase from $17$ whites to $19$ whites, say, so you need to prove this possibility does not occur.

---

Here is my idea for a proof, with some details left to you. To prove that you can reach any number of lights of form $1,3,5,\dots,n$ when the starting configuration has an odd number of white buttons. It suffices to show that in any configuration with an odd number of white buttons less than $n$, there exists a way to increase the number of white buttons. For this to happen, you need to make a move which toggles two black buttons, changing them white.

Given a configuration with an odd number of white buttons, where not all are white, there will exist at least two black buttons. If those black buttons are already at a distance of exactly $2$, then they can both be toggled by pressing the button between them. Otherwise, you can "move" the black button around the circle, by doing a series of moves where you toggle that black button and a white button. There are two directions you can "move" the black button around the circle, clockwise or counterclockwise. One of these directions will bring the black button exactly two spaces away from the other black button. The other directions will cause the two buttons to be adjacent when they meet.